# Save BitMapImage to application folder

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmapimage

I am trying to save BitmapImage in application folder path. I am using following code

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
var resultSaveDialog = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (fileDialog.FileName != "" && resultSaveDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    fileDialog.OpenFile();
    strPath = fileDialog.FileName;
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 20;
    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 20;
    myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(strPath, UriKind.Absolute);
    myBitmapImage.EndInit();                                      
    System.Windows.Media.ImageSource imgSource = myBitmapImage;     
 }
```

I wanna save this `myBitmapImage` to application folder LA_Img. How can i do this .. I am not being able to find any method of it..

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx). See [System.Windows.Media.Imaging-Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms608877.aspx) for derived classes like `JpegBitmapEncoder` or `PngBitmapEncoder`.

Comment: No method in BitMapEncoder for setting image height and width ??

Comment: Why should it be there? Those are properties of the bitmap.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you don't want to simply save it, but instead you want to first manipulate the size, and _then_ save it?

Comment: Well, the bitmap was resized already: DecodePixelWidth, DecodePixelHeight.